# Android-Work Manager OnetimeWorkRequest not Working(Android-Jetpack)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to use Android Jetpack WorkManager but the code is doing nothing.
Here are my sample codes:

1. SampleWorkManager.java

```
    public class SampleWorkManager extends Worker {

        private static final String TAG = "SampleWorkManager";


        public SampleWorkManager(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
            super(context, workerParams);
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Result doWork() {


            Data inputData=getInputData();
            String name=inputData.getString("name");
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork:  name: "+name);


            int number=inputData.getInt("number",0);

            for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
                Log.d(TAG, "doWork:  our number is: "+i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return Result.success();
        }
    }
```

2. MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initWorkManager();
        }

        private void initWorkManager(){

            Log.d(TAG, "initWorkManager:  started");

            Data data=new Data.Builder()
                    .putInt("number",10)
                    .putString("name","First Work")
                    .build();

           Constraints constraints=new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                    .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                    .setRequiresCharging(false)
                    .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SampleWorkManager.class)
                .setInputData(data)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

           WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);

        }
    }
```

also, I am using below dependency:

```
    def work_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

Logcat file

```
11/02 22:32:39: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 28(My AVD).
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.sampleworkmanager/com.example.sampleworkmanager.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 5216 on device 'Pixel_2_API_28_My_AVD_ [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/mpleworkmanage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/mpleworkmanage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/MainActivity: initWorkManager:  started
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1215e80, tid 5251
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe2471cc0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2471cc0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe9bc7740)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
I/mpleworkmanage: Background concurrent copying GC freed 10967(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(164KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1647KB/3MB, paused 4.338ms total 231.484ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2471cc0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe9bc7740)
```

the problem is I am unable to figure out what is going wrong & no task is running in the background.
please help me.

Comment: In your code `oneTimeWorkRequest` isn't defined.

Comment: forget to include, I have edited the code but the problem is the same...

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the code with all the constraints satisfied?
What happens if you run it without any constraints?

Comment: problem is solved after the wifi is turned on but " WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@cfe5da7)" this code is continuously running on the log cat.